# Spring jar dependencies

Tags: spring, jar, dependencies

Trying to build Spring-based application one needs to figure out all necessary dependencies the application will have.

For example, I was using HibernateTemplate, and each time I run the application the ClassNotFound exception comes out. So I “google” for jars that contains this particular class, after search mvnrepository to find appropriate artifact. Always confuse about which version to use.

And it’s happened again and again, and only after few hours and few dozens of dependencies added the application become runnable.

But even after that, I tried to use my app. on different computer with slightly different parameters, and slf4j class not found error appeared, even after testing extensively on the developer machine, still some dependencies missing.

Now it works fine, but I want to distribute my application, and not sure if on another system there will no dependency missing.

So, what is the best practice to determine all necessary dependencies not only at design time but in runtime too? Is there any tool for that?

How one can manage versions confusion, when there are dozens of dependencies each with its own version?

Comment: How is your application packaged?  As a WAR?

Answer (score 0):

They both resolve dependencies, so you keep a dependency file and it does all the heavy lifting of making sure everything is included in your builds.  Use the full spring dependency list.  I had problems with SLF4J too.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-full/1.2.8

Comment: I don't think you understand my question correctly. I use maven on everyday basis, but it cannot read my mind. If I don't include spring-orm dependency, HibenateTemplate will not work. And many times in runtime I found missing dependencies after working with a project for weeks. Like it was with slf4j. This loging framework was not loaded automaticly, as there is no component of my application directly depending on it. But spring tries to use it to log the error that happens only once in weeks. And ClassNotFound exception is thrown. How many hidden dependency are out there and how to find them

Comment: Try to use the full spring repository: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-full/1.2.8